# Having trouble with parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions

I working on a class template where the template itself is not of a variadic type, however the constructor of the class is. I'm trying to take all the values of the parameter pack and store them into a vector, but I can not seem to get the code to compile, I keep getting compiler error messages that the parameter pack must be expanded in this context, and I'm not sure what the proper syntax is. Here is my class:

```
template<class T>
class TableRow {
private:
    std::string id_;
    std::vector<T> values_;

public:
    template<class T, class... Params>
    TableRow( const std::string& id, T firstVal, Params... valuePack ) :
    id_(id) {
        values.push_back( firstVal );
        for ( auto t : (valuePack...) ) {  // Compiler error here
             values_.push_back( t ); 
        }
    }

    // ... other methods
};
```

Other than getting this to compile correctly the only other concern that I have is that is there a way to ensure that all `Params` are of type `T`?

Another words this is what I'm trying to achieve when instantiating this class

```
TableRow<int> trInt1( "Row1", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
TableRow<int> trInt2( "Row2", 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 );

TableRow<float> trFloat1( "Row1", 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f );
TableRow<float> trFloat2( "Row1", 4.5f, 7.9f );

// In the above examples the first two rows are of the same length
// meaning their vector sizes are equal in length therefor they are
// compatible to fit inside of single table. The table is
// a class template that takes type <T> the same type as the RowTable<T>.
// The Table<T>'s constructor accepts a TableRow<T>. 

// With the next two examples of the floats they are both indeed table rows
// but they can not fit into the same table since they are of different length

// The following is what I do not want:
TableRow<char>  row( "row1", 'a', 3, 5, 2.4f, someClass ); 
// This is not allowed, all data types from the 2nd parameter on
// must all be of the same type!
```

---

**EDIT**

I took `liliscent` advise and changed my class template's declaration to look like this:

```
template<class T>
class TableRow {
private:
    std::string id_;
    std::vector<T> values_;

public:
    template<class... Params>
    TableRow( std::string id, Params&&... valuePack ) :
        id_( id ),
        values_ { std::forward<Params>( valuePack )... }
    {}

    std::string getID() const {
        return id_;
    }

    std::vector<T> getValues() const {
        return values_;
    }

    std::size_t getSize() const {
        return values_.size();
    }
};
```

And this now compiles... Thank you for your help as I can now move on with writing the rest of this class. At a later time; once I have my two classes working together if all goes well, I'll accept their answer.

Comment: `std::vector<T> getValues() const` should be `const std::vector<T>& getValues() const` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compile failure is simply a syntax error, you can't use range-based for loop in this way. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for.

For solving the problem, you can use `std::vector`'s `std::initializer_list` based constructor, which ensures all values have the same type automatically.

```
template<class... Args>
TableRow( const std::string& id, Args&&... valuePack )
    : id_(id)
    , values_{ std::forward<Args>(valuePack)... }
{}
```

And I think if you want to further fix the number of elements in your `TableRow`, you should use `std::array`. Then you can have another template parameter `int N` to check at compile time whether certain rows can be put into a table.

Comment: Ah that's what I was missing; `vector's `initialize_list`. Yeah I could use `array`, but I'm preferring to use `vector`...

Comment: However, it doesn't solve the issue of using the first T before peeling off the elements in the parameter pack, unless if I remove that completely and just use the full pack instead.

Comment: You want to use the first `T` before inserting it into the vector ?

Comment: No; I want to push it into the vector first then the param pack.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I don't know why you want this, but it's possible. In your original code, use `values_.push_back( firstVal ); values_.insert(values_.end(), { valuePack... });`.

Comment: It's okay I got it to work without the `initial` value, I even went a step further and I template the `ID` type as well. So now this table can have `ID's` of `string`, `unsigned` etc. that matches to a row of data type `T`.

Comment: If you want to deduce `T` from the pack, you could use `std::common_type_t<Args...>`

Answer (score 0):

The fix of your syntax error:

```
template<class T, class... Params>
TableRow( const std::string& id, T firstVal, Params... valuePack ) :
id_(id) {
    values.push_back( firstVal );
    for ( auto t : { valuePack...} ) { // or { static_cast<T>(valuePack) ...}
         values_.push_back( t ); 
    }
}
```

I suggest to take `vector` directly:

```
TableRow(const std::string& id, std::vector<T> values) :
id_(id), values(std::move(values)) {}
```

With usage a little different:

```
TableRow<int> trInt1( "Row1", { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
TableRow<int> trInt2( "Row2", { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });

TableRow<float> trFloat1( "Row1", { 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f });
TableRow<float> trFloat2( "Row1", { 4.5f, 7.9f });
```